# How to give 'view all' in pagination (magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.In my home page I want to display product in different categories with pagination. I tried the following code, and pagination is working.How to give 'view all' here.

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="catalog/layer_view" before="-" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency"  template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
</block>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
      <action method="setColumnCount"><column_count>6</column_count></action>
      <action method="setProductsCount"><count>0</count></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
         <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"  template="catalog/product/list/pager.phtml"/>
         <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>15</limit></action>
         <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>6</limit></action>
         <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>


      </block>
      <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>6</count></action>
      <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your admin system->configuration.

select catalog tab and select frontend option here you can find option **Allow All Products per Page** select yes and save.

Now view all link is listed in your dropdown.

Comment: Yes but i do not want it in the dropdown. i want it in pagination